# Can I drag and drop to a specific place in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

Is possible to drag and drop a game object into a specific place?

For example, I want to put an LED sprite in the hole of a breadboard sprite.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Im confused by what you mean. Do you mean in the editor, itself? And when you say "specific place" do you mean *absolutely* specific? That is to say, being able to specifically drop an object at (for example) the position (10, 15, 50), and not *roughly* the co-ordinates, like say (10, 15, 50.5)?

Answer (score 1):

I', going to share my drang n drop code and you can work it out from there. Here it is :

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
    public class DropZone : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler 
    {
      public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData) 
      {
          Debug.Log (eventData.pointerDrag.name + " was dropped on " + gameObject.name);
          //Do checks for what is being drop here 
      }
    }
```

Then for the actual item we want to drag we use this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour,
          IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {}

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        //Debug.Log ("OnDrag");
        transform.position = eventData.position;
        }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {}
}
```

For more infromation,solutions and a in-depth look into this problem you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473802/unity3d-ui-calculation-for-position-dragging-an-item/37483329#37483329) question on stackoverflow.